# How can I horizontally align these divs in these boxes?

Tags: html, css

This should be simple, but I can't figure it out.  Below is my code sample.  I want the top two divs in each box to align to the top, and the bottom two divs in each box to align to the bottom.  Basically so the tops and bottoms align in each row.  Sometimes I have extra long content in the second div.  Here is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/APJX8/2/

```
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 25%;">
            <div class="box" style="height:200px;">
                <div>top</div>
                <div>this is an extra extra extra long line that wraps</div>
                <div>right above bottom</div>
                <div>bottom</div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 25%;">
            <div class="box" style="height:200px;">
                <div>top</div>
                <div>right underneath</div>
                <div>right above bottom</div>
                <div>bottom</div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 25%;">
            <div class="box" style="height:200px;">
                <div>top</div>
                <div>right underneath</div>
                <div>right above bottom</div>
                <div>bottom</div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 25%;">
            <div class="box" style="height:200px;">
                <div>top</div>
                <div>right underneath</div>
                <div>right above bottom</div>
                <div>bottom</div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: All ids on a page should be unique. Read about the CSS `bottom` property and how it works with different `position`s. That should get you started.

Comment: Why use tables? Why not use two outer divs for the rows, then display the top and right underneath divs in the first row and the other two divs in the bottom row? Fairly straightforward.

Comment: changed the id's to classes.  Doesn't really matter for this exercise but you are right.

Comment: somebody set this html up for me and I didn't want too big of an overhaul.  Just wanted some quick alignment changes.  This isn't the actual html, it has images and links in it, but I wanted to make it real easy to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible without changing the html at least a little bit.

From what I can tell, you have two options: 1. add another div around the first two divs and another around the bottom two divs. Set the second one to `position: absolute; bottom: 0`, and the first one to `position: absolute; top: 0;`. Set `.box` to `position: relative;`. Absolute positioning will require set height on `.box` to prevent the absolute divs from colliding if the text is too long.

or 2. change to using two divs for the rows and use four boxes in each with the respective divs in the top and bottom rows. You won't need to worry about absolute positioning for this method and it'll be a ton cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I see what you are saying.  This is the case of me trying to make a quick fix to somebody else's code which has a bunch of styles applied to it, so it's not that easy to just switch it up.  But I will try!

Comment: You could also use something similar to #2 by adding a second `tr` to create two rows and move the bottom two divs into the second `tr`. That might actually be cleaner/easier depending on your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

this may help you, u can change the style format to suit your needs... :)

```
    <table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 25%;">
                <div class="box" style="height:200px; vertical-align:top;">
                    <div style="float:left; width: 100%;">top</div>
                    <div style="float:left;  width: 100%;">this is an extra extra extra long line that wraps</div>
                </div>
                <div style="vertical-align:bottom;">
                    <div style="float:left;  width: 100%;">right above bottom</div>
                    <div style="float:left;  width: 100%;">bottom</div>
                </div>

        </td>
        <td style="width: 25%;">
                <div class="box" style="height:200px; vertical-align:top;">
                     <div>top</div>
                     <div>right underneath</div>
                </div>
                <div style="vertical-align:bottom;">
                    <div>right above bottom</div>
                    <div>bottom</div>
                </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 25%;">
            <div class="box" style="height:200px; vertical-align:top;">
                     <div>top</div>
                     <div>right underneath</div>
                </div>
                <div style="vertical-align:bottom;">
                    <div>right above bottom</div>
                    <div>bottom</div>
                </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 25%;">
            <div class="box" style="height:200px; vertical-align:top;">
                     <div>top</div>
                     <div>right underneath</div>
                </div>
                <div style="vertical-align:bottom;">
                    <div>right above bottom</div>
                    <div>bottom</div>
                </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```